# Pyramid scheme formula in PHP?

Tags: php, n-tier-architecture, formula

I'm working on a referral system - the formula is exactly like the pyramid/ponzi scheme.

The system works like this:

The initial user signs up (tier 1)
The initial user refers 3 friends (tier 2)
Each of those 3 friends refer another 3, (tier3)
etc.

What would be the mathematical formula for that?
How could I code up something in PHP where I could enter a number and it will then give me the number of tiers it has gone down and a semi-visual.

ie: I enter 13 - it displays the text `"3 tiers"` and then displays

```
     o
     |
    ooo
   / | \
 ooooooooo
```

Comment: What have you tried and thought so far, how did you fail? People here like to help but almost nobody is going to do your homework for you!

Comment: @markus: Hi, I've researched into the formula, but have no idea how I could code that up in PHP. http://www.mathmotivation.com/money/pyramid-scheme.html (the 2-up). Happy to give it a shot though, then come back here for help if needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [geometric progression (GP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), each tier's count is multiplied by a constant number (3) i.e. 1, 3, 9, 27 etc. You are concerned with the sum of the progression.

Read a simplified explanation about GP here. http://www.intmath.com/series-binomial-theorem/2-geometric-progressions.php

Comment: Once you get your way around GPs and the formula for calculating the count of each tier in the GP, making PHP print something on each tier - that number of times - will be a piece of cake. Cheers!

Comment: That's what it's called! Great - thank you so much. I'll get working on things now :)

Comment: @DT85 Glad to be of help. You're welcome, and I wish you all the best with this! :)